# Remove subfolder from Visual Studio Code Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

My current workspace shows this directory. I would like to remove it so it doesn't appear in my workspace.

According to the documentation that I've read the way to do this is to go to File->Preferenceces -> Workspace Tab and the Add a pattern in the excludes.

However, no pattern that I've tried has worked.

I've tried

```
**/IVAPI/BKP_OLD_CODE/*
**/BKP_OLD_CODE/*
**/*BKP_OLD_CODE*
**/BKP_OLD_CODE
```

Then I click the refresh button on the worksapce explorer but the directory stills shows up. How can I add a patter so that BKP_OLD_CODE does not show up anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, the fact is that, since its a folder, it does not have an extension or prefix! So just use the name of the folder (`BKP_OLD_CODE` in this case) and you are all done!

[image: proof]

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work.Thansk anyway

Comment: I added video as a proof.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but it doesn't work for me. Myabe it's the version?

Comment: I got it to work. Instead of adding it to the works pace the tab right next to it allows me to choose a directory there I chose IVAPI and from there I was able to add the exception. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The `project_name.code-workspace` file can be edited to add paths to the `files.exclude` settings, as follows:

File: `project_name.code-workspace`

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/bin/python3",
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/__*": true,
            "**/.pytest_cache": true,
            "**/*.egg-info": true,
            "**/instance": true,
            "**/venv*": true
        }
    }
}
```